# proper way to measure bandwidth in linux programmatically

Tags: c++, linux, bandwidth

I need to find current bandwidth of my system programmatically.
Am I doing correctly here?

```
 double f1, f2, dif, bandwidth;
std::string bw1, bw2, 
sshObj->exec_ssh_command("rm file1");
sshObj->exec_ssh_command("rm file2");
auto start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
sshObj->exec_ssh_command("cat /proc/net/dev >> file1");
sshObj->exec_ssh_command("cat /proc/net/dev >> file2");
auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end - start;
nic_recv_bw_1 = "cat file1 | grep ens160 | awk '{print $2}'";
nic_recv_bw_1 = "cat file2 | grep ens169| awk '{print $2}'"; 
bw1 = sshObj->exec_ssh_channel_command(nic_recv_bw_1);           
bw2 = sshObj->exec_ssh_channel_command(nic_recv_bw_2);           
f1 = std::stod(bw1);
f2 = std::stod(bw2);
dif = f2 - f1;
bandwidth = dif / elapsed_seconds;
```

`exec_ssh_channel_command` is a function to execute a command through ssh session and gives output as a string . 
 my question.

Comment: Bandwidth of what?

Comment: nic @AlanBirtles

Comment: What do you mean by bandwidth though?

Comment: current bandwidth of received and sent bytes through every nic. @AlanBirtles

Comment: `cat ... | grep ... | awk ...` is an antipattern. Consider `awk '/pattern/ {print $2}' file`

Comment: thanks. is my solution to find bandwidth correct? @MarkSetchell